# is it possible to force google Script returning 404 error?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-404

While publishing a Google Script as webApp, it is allowed to have a GET and a POST HTTP methods per script.

Obviously a GET is to fetch some data. But when you are trying to get an specific value (using a filter parameter, for example) and no value is found, how can you force the script to return a 404 error - not found?

Two possibilities from my point of view:

- returning a 404 error (not sure if it is possible)
- returning always
  an structure to facilitate if there was a match for input data of
  API. Something like:

  {
        {
          "error": "0 if everything is fine else an specific code",
          "errorMessage": "description of possible error"
        },
        "data": empty or fulfilled data depending on query result
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can currently force set response codes in GAS, but your second option sounds feasible. Something like this might work for you:

```
function doGet(e){

  var json = handleResponse(e);


  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json))
                       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Handler function example:

```
function handleResponse(e) {

  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  var param = e.parameter.yourParameter;

  if (param) {

     arr = arr.filter(function(element){

        return element > parseInt(param);

});

   if (arr.length > 0) {

          return {"result":arr};

       }  else {

           return {"error":"no value was found"};

           }

} else {

   return {"error":"query parameter not specified"};

}

}
```

On the receiving end, you can then handle the response based on the property it contains:

```
if ("result" in response) {
   //do something
}

if ("error" in response) {
   //do something
}
```